# Call original implementation after block expectations

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there any possibility to call original implementation from the block matcher?

```
expect(object).to receive(:method) do |argument|
  expect(argument).to eql expected_value

  somehow_call_original_implementation_of_the_method
end
```

When I use `and_call_original` it ignores expectations for argument within a block, just check the method is received:

```
expect(object).to receive(:method) do |argument|
  expect(argument).to eql expected_value
end.and_call_original
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you call `expect_to_receive` with a block? I think that is reserved for `allow_to_receive`, where the block is used as the implementation of the method.

In your case I think you can just change it to something like this:

```
expect(argument).to eql(expected_argument_value)
expect(object).to receive(:method).and_return(expected_value)
object.method
```